# Lenovo IdeaTab A2109 reflash?

Tags: rooting, root-access, lenovo

I have a Lenovo IdeaTab A2109 I'm trying to get working.  When you power it on, it stays on the *`lenovo`* bootup logo.  I'm on a Mac, and I need to know how to reflash (or reinstall, or whatever the term is) Android to it so that it will (hopefully) be usable.

If you have other suggestions on how to get it working, I'm open to those as well.  Oh, and rooting instructions would be nice too (keep in mind I'm on a Mac).

So how do I reinstall Android on this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an [android image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxNORR1JMMjZd3FWQ2hndTgwcGs/view?pref=2&pli=1) that worked.  Here's what I did:

1. Plug in tablet via USB
2. Open Terminal
3. Boot tablet in recovery mode
4. Scroll to 'Update from ADB'
5. In Terminal, run `adb sideload [Path to zip file of image]`
6. Let it run
7. All is well!

I found the link the the image on [www.androidtablets.net](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/useful-files-from-drivers-to-modded-roms.52307/).

Excerpt:

> Stock 4.1.1 (A2109_A411_03_13_121127): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxNORR1JMMjZNTRIUlFlb2JBVTQ
>   ACC89EE042C53BE7CC980DC4DAE6A3ED